# can't create a New Web Application Project in eclipse indigo?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

can anyone help me.I cant create a new web application.I mean i cant find the menu option for it. I downloaded eclipse indigo (java) extracted it any started using it, I also downloaded google app engine SDK,google plugin and GWT.and installed them but i can't find create new web application project option in toolbar nor in menu options.

Comment: Try to install this plugin manually by downloading the [zip file](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html).

Comment: The 'New -> Web Application' menu option is not available in all Eclipse Perspectives, so make sure to switch either to the 'Java' or 'Java EE' Perspective (Window -> Open Perspective -> Java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**File** -> **New** -> **Web Application Project**

You've a problem with the installation of these plugins if you don't have this option. Try to restart the Eclipse.

Execute all the steps of the official [installation instruction](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7).

Comment: I did it hundreds of time Do you think i need some thing else also to be installed

Comment: I followed the official installation instruction it got installed properly with no errors.

Comment: You should haven't any problems if all steps of this instruction were completed successfully. The causes of many failures you can be found in the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Just resolved this exact same problem myself. Highly recommend you download the plugin package to your machine and install it locally. You can download it here:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip

There are instructions to follow and it worked flawlessly. Hope it helps anyone else who is lost on the plugin install.

Answer (score 0):

Once you installed Google App Engine SDK, you should be able to see web application by following this

select **File > New > Web Application Project** from the Eclipse menu.

if not, follow this

select **File > New > Other > Google > Web Application Project**

Official [Instructions](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse#installing)

Answer (score 0):

Depend what you are using i have eclipse kepler and i can't  find "web app prject" butthere is  a little google icon that is google plug in for eclipse when u go there and start using plug in you could find web app and all options of google app engine also can find  "web app"  create project and deploy app.