# Cannot find "New Web Application Project" option in Eclipse Luna with GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

I followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4) to install Google Web Toolkit in a freshly installed Eclipse (Luna). I have Java version 8 on Mac OS 10.7.5.  I restarted Eclipse twice for good measure.  I can see the following installed software:

[image: screenshot of installed software in Eclipse]

I now want to start making a GWT project [as outlined here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html). However I can't find any "New Web Application Project button" or icon.  Here's a screenshot of the dropdown menu under "New".

[image: screenshot of drop-down menu under New]

I found a [previous recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479393/cant-create-a-new-web-application-project-in-eclipse-indigo) to [install from a download](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip) but this option doesn't seem to be available for Luna.

I also found [these FAQs](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#sdkbundle) which say where the SDK is installed; indeed, I have a `/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0` directory.

How can I start a new GWT project? Thanks!

Comment: I had similar issue in Windows 7. I re-installed the eclipse then in worked. https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#multiuser

Comment: I would try to repair the file permission. Next I would start the Console app to see if there is any exception.

Comment: You have the 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' installed which does not have the web development plugins. You probably want the 'Eclipse IDE for Java **EE** Developers' install

Comment: Thanks greg-449 - you are right, [Google's docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse) do indeed say 'The "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" package includes all of the components you will need for web application development.'  So I trashed my Eclipse and installed the EE version, and installed GWT again.  But I still have exactly the same problem, with the same dropdown menu under "New" as before.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Odd. I just did the exact same installation on my MacBook (OS 10.8) and it's working fine.  Even before installing GWT, Eclipse was giving a completely different-looking menu under "New".  Perhaps I didn't fully uninstall the old Eclipse on my original computer?

Comment: What is your using java version to start eclipse? It must be minumum 1.7 for Luna.

Answer (score 2):

File -> New -> Other -> Google -> Web Application Project

Comment: Sorry, there is no "Google" option under "File -> New -> Other" for me (even after reinstalling Eclipse with the 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers")...

Comment: My `Eclipse IDE` also has not `Google` in the `File -> New -> Other` option.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Eclipse from command prompt with `-clean` option as
  `./eclipse -clean`

This should make all the GWT related views available.

Setting `-clean` option will remove all the OSGi and Eclipse Runtime cache data.
This will also clean the caches used to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry data.

Comment: This sounds promising - thanks!  When I type `./eclipse -clean`, Eclipse launches, but there is still no GWT button. I get the output: `org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: .../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.5.0.20140606-0033.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
java.lang.ClassCastException: ...` .

Comment: do you have correct permissions on your Eclipse directory? I am also getting similar output but without last ClassCastException. Last line in my log is :
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback.
Also please try with fresh workspace.

Comment: I've tried fresh eclipse install, fresh workspace, nothing.  Also on a macbook.  I'm now trying to put the eclipse install in my home directory instead of applications, but I can't see how that would matter.